# Flutter - Firebase Notification History

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey guys i try to build a Widget which contains a history with all previously notification. How can I get these old notifications? Is there a way to get it without storing the notifications in my database? I use the Firebase database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the future is possible, but older notifications are not reachable. You can use the Cloud Functions for it. If you want to an example you can use [this doc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) But if you don't want to any storage, unfortunately it's not possible for now. Firebase (FCM) is not store the any push notf. data